# Count the number of comparisons and permutations by round and the summation of the sorting algorithm

Tags: c++, sorting

```
void sort(int a[], int n)
{
    for (int i = n - 2; i ≥ 0; i--)
    {
        int temp = a[i];
        int j;
        for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (a[j] > temp)
                a[j - 1] = a[j];
            else
                break;
        }
        a[j - 1] = temp;
    }
}
```

> Count the number of comparisons and permutations by round and the summation of the sorting algorithm  with a : {4, 7, 12, 7, 1, 12}

Comment: What do you mean by count the number of permutations? Can you give an example with an input and the expected output?

Comment: You haven't asked a question yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using helper variables:

```
void sort(int a[], int n)
{
    int outerLoop = 0;
    int comparisons = 0;
    for (int i = n - 2; i ≥ 0; i--)
    {
        outerLoop++;
        int temp = a[i];
        int j;
        for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            comparisons++;
            if (a[j] > temp)
                a[j - 1] = a[j];
            else
                break;
        }
        a[j - 1] = temp;
    }
    //Do something with outerLoop and comparisons...
}
```